# Junit Runner Class Unable to locate Step Definition file

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

JUnit Runner class is unable to locate the Steps definition file  with project structure Below:
**src/test/java/com/testSteps/TestSteps.java** 
and JunitRunner class under
**src/test/java/com/cucumbertestrunner/TestRunner**

[[image: (Project Hierarchy is attached Below)]                                       Following is the syntax of JUnitRunner class

```
package com.cucumbertestrunner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features ={"src/test/resources/TestSteps.feature"},
glue ={"src/test/java/com"},strict = true,plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**Running the  TestRunner.java as JUnit Test shows following exception:**

at cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailure(JUnitReporter.java:134)
         cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailureOrIgnoreStep(JUnitReporter.java:122)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.result(JUnitReporter.java:91)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:281)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into the TestSteps class, and what the step methods contain. Throwing the PendingException is the default implementation for the steps. You have to actually implement what the step should do.

Apart from that, I suggest to setthe location of the steps as a package, because steps are defined in classes and those have to be located in the classpath.

For example

```
 glue = {"com.teststeps"}
```

I also suggest to refer to the feature files in the classpath, as they are located in the resources folder

```
features = {"classpath:TestSteps.feature}
```

Comment: I tried exactly  your mentioned solution "@CucumberOptions(features ={"classpath:TestSteps.feature"}, glue = {"com.teststeps"}," BUT still same issue

Comment: Check the content of the TestSteps, I assume the PendingException is thrown by the step itself and it's not due to your set up. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeas it was by mistake , One of the methods in the Test Steps file was throwing Pending Exception. Many Thanks for your help :)